# Ubuntu 18.04 is apt-get broken

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package, apt

```
$ sudo apt update
     
/usr/bin/apt: 17: /usr/bin/apt: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

$sudo apt-get update 

/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: �: not found

/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: �@8: not found

/usr/bin/apt-get: 1: /usr/bin/apt-get: ELF: not found

/usr/bin/apt-get: 15: /usr/bin/apt-get: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I don't see any extra `"("` but this massage keep showing

```
 - List item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this command "sudo apt-get install --reinstall apt" if there is a synax error and you can use "apt-get" instead, it could resolve your problem. Additionally, you could try to use "apt-get" in place of apt until you find the synax error (Ex: sudo apt-get update).